# Intellij throwing Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main at run time while running on VM ONLY

Tags: java, maven, automation, cucumber, virtual-machine

I have setup the cucumber project on Window VM on intellij editor. While execution of feature file I am getting below error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.cucumber.core.cli.Main    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
```

How ever when I run this same program on my local it works fine. Might be some permission issue on VM not sure. In run configuration system is finding the class.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have differences in class path libraries (JARs versions).
Check your dependencies tree on both environments and compare.

```bash
mvn dependency:tree
```